# Symfony2 Swap 2 objects primary key Doctrine

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, swap

I've got myself an entity

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="position", type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $position;
```

The Id is the primary key but I'll sort the array with position. I want to make functions to swap 2 of the items when sorting or move them up and down.

How can I make a constructor that will increment each new object I create automatically?

I've tried:

```
 /**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->position = $this->id+1;
}
```

But the Id is assigned after persisting the object so each one has position set to 1. Do I need to use Life Cycle Callbacks?

Answer (score 0):

Lifecycle callbacks could work to do what you want but you have to be aware that if you modify an entity after flushing to the database you're gonna have to flush again to save the new information.